# Sort an array in Javascript based on the order defined in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
let x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let y = ['z', 'c', 'a']
```

I want to sort `y` based on the order defined in `x` . 
I have tried this approach:

```
y.sort((a,b) => { return x.indexOf(b) - x.indexOf(a) })
```

The problem is that **it does not keep the unique order defined in `x`**

```js
let x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let y = ['z', 'c', 'a']

y.sort((a,b) => { return x.indexOf(b) - x.indexOf(a) })

console.log(y);
```

I want to receive the output: `['a', 'c', 'z']` instead of `['c', 'a', 'z']`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are sorting descending, because you take the index of the second parameter first and vice versa.

Then you have a problem with unknow items, they get `-1` and are sorted on top, but you need this items to sort to bottom.

---

You could take [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) as default value to sort unknown items to the bottom.

[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` for items wo are not in the array, `+ 1` gives a value which is usable with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) and `Infinity` is a value, big enough to move the item to bottom.

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    y = ['z', 'c', 'a'];

y.sort((a, b) => (x.indexOf(a) + 1 || Infinity) - (x.indexOf(b) + 1 || Infinity));

console.log(y); // a c z
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use `Array.prototype.sort` and pass to it a sorting function that sorts based on the index position of the element in the other array(if it exists). See comments in sorting function for more details:

```js
let x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let y = ['z', 'c', 'a'];

const sort = (positions, arr) => {
  const sorter = (a, b) => {
    const idxA = positions.indexOf(a);
    const idxB = positions.indexOf(b);

    //If a doesn't exist in positions, it should come after whatever it's being compared to
    if (idxA === -1) {
      return 1;
    }

    //If a does exist in positions, but b doesnt, b should come after
    if (idxB === -1) {
      return -1
    }

    //Compare the indexes since they both exist
    return idxA - idxB;
  }

  return arr.sort(sorter);
}

console.log(sort(x, y));
```